# finding volume of region with cross sections

Tags: calculus

> The base of a solid is the region is between the line of $y=4$ and the parabola $y=x^2$ the cross sections of the solid that are perpendicular to the $x$-axis are semicircles. What is the volume?

So the question I have on this is whether or not I'm going to need to divide the integral by $2$ since they are semi circles, not circles. When I divide by $2$, I get $\frac{16π}{3}$; however, when I don't divide, I get $\frac{512π}{15}$. Are either of these correct, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

What is one way to look at the area of the base of the solid? Here is one: $$\int_{y=0}^{2} 2x \ dy.$$ 
We're cutting it into horizontal slices with length $2x$ and height $dy$.

Similarly what function of $x$ would describe the area of the semicircle?

Then put that function instead of $2x$ in the formula for the area of the base of the solid.